# Math formula not returning correct answer

Tags: java, android, math, methods

So i'm trying to make a simple calculator to calculate a wilks score. I'm not getting the correct answer which i'm sure is because i'm not setting up the formula correctly. If I pass in a weight of 180, squat of 300, bench of 300, and deadlift of 400 in lbs I should be getting a wilks of 305.78 but i'm getting 2.0414858^-5

Heres my calcWilks method

```
   public double calcWilks(double weight, double squat, double bench, double deadLift) {

    double a = -216.0475144;
    double b = 16.2606339;
    double c = -0.002388645;
    double d = -0.00113732;
    double e = Math.pow(7.01863, -6);
    double f = Math.pow(-1.291, -8);
    double x = weight;
    double coeff;
    double score;

    coeff = 500 / (a + (b*x) + (c* Math.pow(x, 2))+ (d* Math.pow(x, 3))
            + (e* Math.pow(x, 4)) + (f* Math.pow(x, 5)));

    double total = squat + bench + deadLift;
    score = coeff* total;
    return score;
}
```

and heres a link to the actual formaula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks_Coefficient

I'm trying to use the Male formula

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Math.pow(7.01863, -6) != 7.01863E-06`.

Comment: ``Math.pow(7.01863, -6);`` is not the same as ``7.01863E-06``...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look over that!  I'm still having issues with getting the correct result.  Getting 538.8456 but I should be getting 305.78.

Comment: You are using pounds, you should be using kg.

Comment: Ahhh your probably right why didn't I think of that thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` coefficient's value in the wikipedia page is

```
7.01863E-06
```

but you've used

```
Math.pow(7.01863, -6)
```

That's not the same thing:

```
7.01863E-06 = 7.01863 * Math.pow(10, -6).
```

Just use the value `7.01863E-06` (or `7.01863e-6`) directly.

(Same problem with `f`)

---

Also, note that the inputs to the formula should be in kilograms; not in pounds, as you state in the question.

Comment: ugh thank you that was a stupid mistake. I think I still have a problem somewhere else too I'm now getting 538.8456 but it should  be 305.78